# SSRS Ignore Filters Based on a specific Filter used

Tags: reporting-services

Good day

I have a SSRS report that has 4 filters.
One of the 4 filters is a "Search Parameter".

When the user uses the "Search Parameter" (field/filter, types something in), I want to ignore the other three filters despite them having values or not.

I've tried CASE/SWITCH statements in the Expression of the Parameter (DataSet Properties), but no luck.

Does anyone have an idea on how I can get this done

Comment: Are you applying these filters at a tablix/chart level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Filter is quick and convenient but only allows `AND` relationships between the filter criteria and you want an `OR` relationship here.

The good news is that you can make more complex filter logic by using expressions. We will create a boolean filter expression that evaluates to whether you want to filter the row or not and compare this to `True`.

Have only one filter criterion and click the expression editor button. Make the expression something like:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Parameters!SearchParameter.Value), Fields!Field1.Value = Parameters!Field1Parameter AND Fields!Field2.Value = Parameters!Field2Parameter AND Fields!Field3.Value = Parameters!Field3Parameter, Fields!SearchField.Value LIKE "*" & Parameters!SearchParameter.Value & "*")
```

Make the expression type be `Boolean`, the Operator `=` and the Value `True`.